# Create list item which will link and navigate to new list item?

Tags: list, custom-form, list-item

I've been trying to get this to work but need some direction. Got a requirement for a list item that on submission would create another list item and link to it. So basically a lookup on the ID of the linked item on the other list.

I've got the 2 lists but the problem might be the ID won't be created until the other list item has been submitted. I'm thinking Workflow to try create an auto ID and have the 'Submit' button somehow save the original list item and navigate to the new form?

Am I on the right track here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create field on list 1 to store value -> Create a workflow so when you create item on List 1, it creates item on list 2. Then waits 1 minute, then updates List 1 with ID from List 2. This way the pause will allow the ID to be generated before attempting to update it. This works if you don't need immediate access to the ID link and can wait 1 minute for it to update.

[image: Workflow]

If you want it to link both ways, create a column in list 2 to store list 1's value and have it update when the workflow creates the list item.

On new -> Create item in list 2 -> Create item in List 2 and update [ID Link Column] with [ID] list 1 -> Pause for 1 minute -> Update List 1 [ID link Column] with [ID] list 2

Comment: sounds promising thanks Ryan, I will try implement this

Comment: Instead of pause for duration, you could use Wait for created by to equal CurrentItem:Created By. I'd imagine the ID for the entry would need to be generated before Created by is assigned. This way you don't have a bunch of workflow instances paused for a minute.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this can be by creating an `ItemAdded` event handler in the first list. In the event handler code add an item in the second list and retrieve the ID of this newly created item and then finally update the lookup column in the first list using above ID.

Answer (score 0):

Why not submitting the second item first using REST or JSOM, and when it's submitted you get the ID and use it to link and submit the first item.